# Insert contacts in google to use in WhatsApp using c#

Tags: c#, contacts

I hope you can help me:

I have a database with several phone numbers and names

I need to create a process in C# that runs automatically and inserts these values ​​into a Google account that is linked to WhatsApp.

With the result that when opening WhatsApp, the contacts appear with the name

Can you give me indications what to look for or where to start, because I have not been able to find anything useful

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Have you taken a look at the People API from google?

https://developers.google.com/people

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to ask the user to sign-in to their google account you can use the `people.createContact` api endpoint to create contacts in their google contacts account.

While there will be a delay until the contacts update thought these various systems this is likely the best you can do. `HttpClient` should be able to make the required API calls :)

sources:

1. https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

I leave you the answer, which contains: get the contacts from google and be able to insert. If someone has the functions to update and delete it would be great, that would be everything

```
// Genéricas
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

// People API
//using Google.Apis.People.v1;
//using Google.Apis.People.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1;
using Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1.Data;


// Docs API
using Google.Apis.Docs.v1;
using Google.Apis.Docs.v1.Data;

// Drive API
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data; // Para el tipo File

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

//using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
//using System.Collections.Immutable;
using Person = Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1.OtherContactsResource;
using Google.Apis.Requests;
using insert_contacts_google.Mediador;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;

namespace insert_contacts_google
{
    class Program
    {

    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
    // at ~/.credentials/docs.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json
    static string[] Scopes = { DocsService.Scope.Documents,
                               DocsService.Scope.DriveFile,
                               PeopleServiceService.Scope.Contacts };

   

    static string ApplicationName = "importGoogle";
    static PeopleServiceService peopleService;
    static UserCredential Credential;
    private static int total = 0;
    public static List<String> lNumG = new List<String>();
    public static Dictionary<string, string> dDatWs = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public static Tools_CPE tools = new Tools_CPE() { Credentials = glbCredenciales, Url = glbWebService };


    // Los datos del proyecto creado para VB
    static ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets()
    {
        ClientId = ".....",
        ClientSecret = ".."
    };



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main");

        string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
            Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

        // Directorio donde se guardarán las credenciales
        credPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/Tutorial-Google-APIs-VB");

        Credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            secrets,
            Scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        //Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);

        // Mostrar los contactos
        getContactGoole();
        getContactWs();

        setPeople(peopleService);
    }

    private static void getContactGoole()
    {
        // Create Drive API service.
        peopleService = new PeopleServiceService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = Credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        // Lista de los contactos (People)
        Console.WriteLine("Contactos:");

        // Este muestra todos los contactos
        GetPeople(peopleService, null);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"Hay {total} contactos / People");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static bool GetPeople(PeopleServiceService service, string pageToken)
    {
        bool control = true;

        // Define parameters of request.
        PeopleResource.ConnectionsResource.ListRequest peopleRequest =
                service.People.Connections.List("people/me");

        //
        // Lista de campos a usar en RequestMaskIncludeField:
        // https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get
        //

        peopleRequest.RequestMaskIncludeField = new List<string>()
                {"person.names", "person.phoneNumbers", "person.emailAddresses",
                  "person.birthdays", "person.Addresses"
                };


        if (pageToken != null)
        {
            peopleRequest.PageToken = pageToken;
        }

        ListConnectionsResponse people = peopleRequest.Execute();

        if (people != null && people.Connections != null && people.Connections.Count > 0)
        {
            total += people.Connections.Count;
            foreach (var person in people.Connections)
            {
                /*
                Console.Write(person.PhoneNumbers != null ? ($"{person.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault().Value} - ") : "");
                Console.Write(person.EmailAddresses != null ? ($"{person.EmailAddresses.FirstOrDefault().Value} - ") : "");
                Console.Write(person.Addresses != null ? ($"{person.Addresses.FirstOrDefault()?.City} - ") : "");
                Console.Write(person.Names != null ? ($"{person.Names.FirstOrDefault().DisplayName} - ") : "");
                */


                if (person.PhoneNumbers != null)
                {
                    String num = person.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault().Value;
                    lNumG.Add(num);
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            if (people.NextPageToken != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine($"{total} contactos mostrados hasta ahora. Pulsa una tecla para seguir mostrando contactos.");
                Console.WriteLine();

                GetPeople(service, people.NextPageToken);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            control = false;
            Console.WriteLine("No se han encontrado contactos.");
        }

        return control;
    }

    static void setPeople(PeopleServiceService service)
    {
        Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1.Data.Person person = new Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1.Data.Person();
        Name chef = new Name();
        chef.GivenName = "FirstName2";
        chef.FamilyName = "FamilyName3";
        person.Names = new List<Name>();
        person.Names.Add(chef);

        PhoneNumber phone = new PhoneNumber();
        phone.Value = "04040404";
        phone.Type = "mobile";
        person.PhoneNumbers = new List<PhoneNumber>();
        person.PhoneNumbers.Add(phone);

        EmailAddress email = new EmailAddress();
        email.Type = "work";
        email.Value = "firstname2.familyname2@something.com";
        person.EmailAddresses = new List<EmailAddress>();
        person.EmailAddresses.Add(email);


        ContactToCreate contactToCreate = new ContactToCreate();
        contactToCreate.ContactPerson = person;
        BatchCreateContactsRequest request = new BatchCreateContactsRequest();

        request.Contacts = new List<ContactToCreate>();
        request.Contacts.Add(contactToCreate);
        request.ReadMask = "names";

        BatchCreateContactsResponse reply = service.People.BatchCreateContacts(request).Execute();

    }
}
}
```